# android zxing captureActivity NPE on ViewfinderView

Tags: android, zxing

I've integrated the zxing library into my app. I have a runtime error when i try to scan a QR code. It's caused by a NPE when trying to inflate a ViewFinderView object from XML. In my project all my app's code resides in a package called com.carefreegroup and all the zxing code resides in com.google.zxing.client.android. I've done some logging to test whether the ViewFinderView is null and it does in fact come back as null.

Can anyone tell me why this object is not getting inflated, could it be a package problem?

```
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.carefreegroup/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2850)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2889)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:192)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1236)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4625)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2834)
01-02 15:09:53.887: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    ... 12 more
```

I can post my manifest file if needed to check packages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've copied the project's UI including `CaptureActivity` and `ViewfinderView`. Don't do that -- it's not OK and not wholly permitted. You need to write your own app and reuse parts that you understand, into an app that you understand. Here indeed you pasted a bunch of code incompletely, and it doesn't work when you do that.

Integrate by Intent, or write your own app. In any event please do not use `com.google.zxing.client.android` like this.

Comment: Hi Sean, ok thanks for the reply, my boss would have liked it fully integrated so there is only one apk to be downloaded to service our company's clients. I've explained to him that it's how android is intended to work "glueing" functionality together via intents. Is there a way to point my app to the app store to download the zxing app as my app is being installed. We'd like things as seamless as possible. Thanks again Matt

Comment: The IntentIntegrator example code already handles download from Google Play. To be clear: you're welcome to integrate the code. It's copying and pasting so much without understanding it that causes problems. It generates support questions (like this), it generates user confusion when they think they're using BS, and most important if you don't change your namespace/manifest, you'll be intercepting intents for BS. Write an integrated scanning app sure, but write *your* app.

Comment: Hi Sean. I think people would start make their apps if there will be **any** documentation to zxing.

Comment: @Igor I don't understand your sentence. Are you looking for this? http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent  People are already using it too much...

Comment: Thanks, but no. I need to include capture frame into my activity. And I have also to try to adapt your project to my code.

Comment: OK, but the code is already javadoc'ed. You haven't said what documentation you think is missing, but, if you want to modify open source code that's really up to you. Nobody owes you a manual. Most of what people mean when they say "adapt your project" means clone it, which harms our app by copying the namespace/Intent declarations, and uses our trademarks improperly. Why would I document how to do that?

Comment: Hi Sean Owen, because I don't know how to reach you I'm writing here. Is zxing needs a scanner app installed in the phone? I am trying to get an answer for this. I do not want the scanner app to be installed on my phone and also I don't want it with the help of Intents. How can I do this? Please help me

Comment: I'm still not sure why NullPointerException occurred in this case. But it got fixed for me when I changed the package name throughout the Zxing library project, including the intent action names. It is obvious that it happened because ViewFinderView could not be found by findViewById, but why viewFinderView could not be found is still mystery to me.

Comment: It would be nice if someone posted an answer that explains why this NullPointerException occurred. The documentations could warn developers that the package names must be changed when including Zxing as library, if that is actually causing problems.

Comment: You are not supposed to use it as a library at all