# Zxing how to make scan result propagate back to calling activity

Tags: android, zxing

I've integrated the ZXing code into my app. I was told not to copy and paste the whole libray into my app but rather take the parts i need. I started with the capture activity and then copied it's dependencies into my app. I changed the intent filter from zxing one to my intent filter. oh and i had to change a package name in the capture.xml.

It seems to work fine, when my activity calls startActivityForResult() the scanner starts. The problem is when i scan i QRcode, the scan result does not propagate back to my calling activity, instead it asks how to finish off the action eg sms, email etc.

how can i make the scan results come back to my activity's onActivityResult?

Thanks in advance matt

```
 Button signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsignin);

        alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.3F, 0.8F); //Set opacity - Range 0.0 to 1.0
        alpha.setDuration(0); // Set animation duration
        alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Maintaining the effect to the button
        signin.startAnimation(alpha);
        signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onclicked sign in");

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.carefreegroup.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");

                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
```

.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "in onActivityResult");
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.e(TAG, "result ok");

//              
                ///////////////////////////////



                tagScanTime  = new DateTime();

                DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MMM/yy h:mmaa");
                String formattedScanTime = df.print(tagScanTime);
                Log.e(TAG, "formatted tag scan time = " + formattedScanTime);



                 contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
//              Toast.makeText(this, "scanner has found " + contents,
//                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 //get info from tag that has been just scanned
                    String[] splitPayload = contents.split(",");

                    tagType = splitPayload[0];
                    tagCompany = splitPayload[1];
                    tagCompany = nfcscannerapplication.getCompId();
                    //tagPerson = splitPayload[2];
                    cursor = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromCarer();
...............
..............
..............
```

.

```
<activity android:name=".CaptureActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: "I was told not to copy and paste the whole libray into my app but rather take the parts i need." -- I do not know who told you that. The ZXing team generally says "do not copy it at all -- use `IntentIntegrator` to communicate with the separate Barcode Scanner app".

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi it was sean owen who said i can use parts that i understand and that it was ok to write an integrated app. Well that's how i understood it. here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124329/android-zxing-captureactivity-npe-on-viewfinderview I can already use the zxing in the way you are suggesting, but my boss wants it integating as one app so his customer just download one apk. Have you any ideas how to make the result come back to my activty? thanks

Comment: He wrote: "You need to write your own app and reuse parts that you understand, into an app that you understand". So, you need to spend a fair bit of time, reading through the ZXing code base, until you understand it. At that point, hopefully the solution to your problem will become evident. Personally, I stick with `IntentIntegrator`.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok thanks, i know what you mean, i'm happy how it works now. It's my boss that would prefer the integration. i'll keep reading

Comment: I did think that the result of startActivityForResult always comes back to onActivityResult?

Comment: Only if the activity in question was written for `startActivityForResult()`. Off the cuff, it sounds like you are starting a different activity than the one that `IntentIntegrator` would access, or perhaps you are missing an extra or something that the activity uses to change its post-scan behavior.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks you were correct, in the Intents class i changed the package name of the ACTION string from zxing to my package and intent eg public static final String ACTION = "com.carefreegroup.SCAN"; It now sends the results back to my calling activity. Thanks if you'd like to make an answer i'll accept

Comment: You can certainly reuse parts of the Android app intelligently. The spirit is "do not copy it *all*" rather than "do not copy it *at all*". Copying the whole thing usually means you clone the manifest, which interferes with our Intent. It also clones the UI and makes people think they're using our app when they're not and we get support calls. (It's also not permitted under the license.) My general guide is: if you're starting from our app you're probably doing it wrong. I hope you have not copied the UI. The typo that underlies your problem is exactly what we want to avoid.