# NullPointerException in findViewbyId(R.id.viewfinder_view) in ZXing Library

Tags: android, zxing

I am trying to intergation ZXing library with my android app.

I followed the respective steps to build ZXing2.3 as a lib project (by adding core/ as a jar into android/)
Now this ZXing lib project seems to compile fine.

Then I referenced it in my application, but when Capture Activity is launched, there is a NullPointerException as it is not able to find a particular Custom View. But when I look at the respective layout file, everything seems fine. And I did not touch/modify the ZXing lib code in any way.

So I presume that I am missing some integration step.

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks
Sunny

PLEASE NOTE: THE ZXING LIB CODE IS NOT BEING COPIED INTO MY APP. THE LIB IS BEING REFERENCED AS AN ANDROID LIB PROJECT.

```
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.demo.abcdemo/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:157)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1210)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5505)
06-17 20:27:41.996: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2936)
```

Comment: logcat will be helpful with some more code

Comment: done. pls let me know if anything else is required

Comment: What is at line 157 in CaptureActivity.java?

Comment: The code that i pasted above      viewfinderView.setCameraManager(cameraManager);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason behind this issue.

ZXing source code has a number of switch statements using `R.id.someViewId`
Now these do not work in android and comparison has to be done via if statements.

Now when i initially included a reference to this lib in my app, I did not get these errors. This I suppose was because the ZXing lib was not compiled properly. So all the views never existed and hence the Null Pointer Exception.

When I finally cleaned and compiled the code, I found all these errors for switch statements. If these are converted to if statements, the lib project works smoothly with any app.

With the above, I actually have a request for @Sean Owen, one of the owners of this lib project. 
I am sure there must be some reason with which you have switch statements for R.id.someViewId but since it does not work, I am sure it must not be working at your end also. 
Could you please modified the code, so that the lib could be used?

And one again I would like to mention that I am not copying the ZXing lib code into my app directly, I am just using it as a lib project and referencing in my app.

Thanks and regards, 
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

**Error at:**

```
viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
  viewfinderView.setCameraManager(cameraManager);
```

**This indicates-**

You are trying to use `setCameraManager` method on `viewfinderView` which is null.

**Possible causes:**

1) Your xml file defined in `CaptureActivity.java` file doesn't have id `viewfinder_view`.

2) Your CaptureActivity.java file is having wrong way to set the layout xml that isn't recognized by the application.

Correct way-

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.CaptureActivity);
        // some more code
}
```

**UPDATE:**

That is why you are getting the error -

You've copied the project's UI including `CaptureActivity` and `ViewfinderView`. Don't do that -- it's not OK and not wholly permitted. You need to write your own app and reuse parts that you understand, into an app that you understand. Here indeed you pasted a bunch of code incompletely, and it doesn't work when you do that.

Integrate by Intent, or write your own app. In any event please do not use `com.google.zxing.client.android` like this.

And as quoted by the questioner -

> Will get fixed by changing the package name throughout the Zxing
>   library project, including the intent action names. It is obvious that
>   it happened because `ViewFinderView` could not be found by`findViewById`.

Complete here - [android-zxing-captureactivity-npe-on-viewfinderview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124329/android-zxing-captureactivity-npe-on-viewfinderview).

Comment: no that doesnt seem to be the issue. I have pasted more code above. please have a look.

Comment: @Sunny - See the update that can point you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did not copy any code into my app from this ZXing lib. I have mentioned that in my OP also. I am using this lib and this code that i have pasted here is from that lib only which is creating the issue. I have found the reason and I am not sure how it is working for anyone who is using this lib. I shall mention that as an answer.

Comment: @Sunny  u got solution

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion this line seems suspicious:

> cameraManager = new CameraManager(getApplication());

Try alternatives like :

1. getApplicationContext()
2. CameraActivity.this
3. getActivity() for fragments
4. this

P.S. I have never used zxing library but if the cameraManager that you are setting is null then it will give null pointer exception.

First thing you can do is to check cameraManager==null and see if it is null.